# R regex find last occurrence of delimiter

Tags: regex, r, string

I'm trying to get the ending for email addresses (ie .net, .com, .edu, etc.) but the portion after the @ can have multiple periods.

```
library(stringi)

strings1 <- c(
    'test@aol.com',
    'test@hotmail.com',
    'test@xyz.rr.edu',
    'test@abc.xx.zz.net'
)

list1 <- stri_split_fixed(strings1, "@", 2)
df1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,list1))

    > list2 <- stri_split_fixed(df1$X2, '.(?!.*.)', 2);list2
[[1]]
[1] "aol.com"

[[2]]
[1] "hotmail.com"

[[3]]
[1] "xyz.rr.edu"

[[4]]
[1] "abc.xx.zz.net"
```

Any suggestions to get something like this:

```
    X1            X2  X3
1 test       aol.com com
2 test   hotmail.com com
3 test    xyz.rr.edu edu
4 test abc.xx.zz.net net
```

EDIT:
Another attempt:

```
> list2 <- stri_split_fixed(df1$X2, '\.(?!.*\.)\w+', 2);list2
Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\."
```

Comment: Your desired result doesn't go with your `strings1` vector

Comment: With `stringi` you can also do `data.frame(stri_match(strings1, regex = "(.*)@(.*[.](.*))")[,-1])`, borrowing the regex from one of the answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are a few approaches. The first seems particularly straight foward and the second particularly short.

**1) sub** That can be done with a an application of `sub` in R to produce each column:

```
data.frame(X1 = sub("@.*", "", strings1), 
           X2 = sub(".*@", "", strings1), 
           X3 = sub(".*[.]", "", strings1), 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
    X1            X2  X3
1 test       aol.com com
2 test   hotmail.com com
3 test    xyz.rr.edu edu
4 test abc.xx.zz.net net
```

**2) strapplyc** Here is an alternative using the gsubfn package that is particularly short.  This returns a character matrix.  `strappylyc` returns the matches to the portions of the pattern in parentheses.   The first set of parantheses matches everything before @, the second set of parentheses matches everything after @ and the last set of parentheses matches everything after the last dot.

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- "(.*)@(.*[.](.*))"
t(strapplyc(strings1, pat, simplify = TRUE))

     [,1]   [,2]            [,3] 
[1,] "test" "aol.com"       "com"
[2,] "test" "hotmail.com"   "com"
[3,] "test" "xyz.rr.edu"    "edu"
[4,] "test" "abc.xx.zz.net" "net"
```

**2a) read.pattern**  `read.pattern` also in the gsubfn package can do it using the same `pat` defined in (2):

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- "(.*)@(.*[.](.*))"
read.pattern(text = strings1, pat, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving a data.frame similar to (1) except the column names are `V1`, `V2` and `V3`.

**3) strsplit** The overlapping extractions make it difficult to do with `strsplit` but we can do it with two applications of `strsplit`.  The first `strsplit` splits at the @ and the second uses everything up to the last dot to split on.  This last `strsplit` always produces an empty string as the first split string and we delete this using `[, -1]`.  This gives a character matrix:

```
 ss <- function(x, pat) do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, pat))
 cbind( ss(strings1, "@"), ss(strings1, ".*[.]")[, -1] )
```

giving the same answer as (2).

**4) strsplit/sub** This is a mix of (1) and (3):

```
cbind(do.call(rbind, strsplit(strings1, "@")), sub(".*[.]", "", strings1))
```

giving the same answer as (2).

**4a)** This is another way to use `strsplit` and `sub`.  Here we append a @ followed by the TLD and then split on @.

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub("(.*[.](.*))", "\\1@\\2", strings1), "@"))
```

giving the same answer as (2).

**Update** Added additional solutions.

Comment: The first sub replaces @ and everything thereafter (.*) with nothing "", the second replaces everything (.*) up to @ with nothing and the third replaces everything (.*) up to a dot ([.]) with nothing.  `stringsAsFaactors=FALSE` is optional and ensures the results are stored as character rather than factor.

Answer (score 10):

A `read.table` + `file_ext` approach (not regex but pretty easy):

```
dat <- read.table(text=strings1, sep="@")
dat$V3 <- tools::file_ext(strings1)
dat

##     V1            V2  V3
## 1 test       aol.com com
## 2 test   hotmail.com com
## 3 test    xyz.rr.edu edu
## 4 test abc.xx.zz.net net
```

Here's a purely regex approach:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(strings1, "@|\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)", perl=TRUE))

##     [,1]   [,2]        [,3] 
## [1,] "test" "aol"       "com"
## [2,] "test" "hotmail"   "com"
## [3,] "test" "xyz.rr"    "edu"
## [4,] "test" "abc.xx.zz" "net"
```

Comment: So many hidden gems in the R base packages like `utils` and `tools`. `file_ext` is basically just a `regexpr` wrapper, but it's neat and already sorted out for you.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a negate lookahead `regex` that should give you the last `.word` of that line.

```
\.(?!.*\.)\w+
```

Comment: Just because your syntax is not correct doesn't mean the regex is not correct. try for yourself [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Great. Short, effective and concise.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using basic regex, assuming df1$X2 is a character vector:

```
df1 <- cbind(df1, X3 = regmatches(df1$X2, regexpr('\\.[A-Z|a-z]*$', df1$X2)))
df1$X3 <- gsub("\\.", "", df1$X3)
```