# Remove characters after last occurrence of delimiter - but keep characters when delimiter occurs once at the beginning

Tags: r, regex

Sorry for the awkward title - very open for suggestions how to better phrase it...

This is very similar to [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289681/r-regex-find-last-occurrence-of-delimiter), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857694/remove-everything-after-the-last-underscore-of-a-column-in-r) and [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900070/regex-to-grep-all-numbers-after-the-second-last-underscore/4900179#4900179). All those questions have a solution that would remove after "every last" occurrence of the delimiter (most often the underscore), including when it occurs at the beginning of the string.

I need to keep those strings where the delimiter occurs only once, at the beginning of the string.

In the example, for `x[3]` and `x[5]`, I'd like to keep "-3" and "-5". My first attempt keeps -5, but not -3...

```r
x <- c("1 - 2","2-1", "-3", "4", "-5-6")

gsub("(.*)\\-.*$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "1 " "2"  ""   "4"  "-5"

gsub("\\-[^\\-].*$", "", x)
#> [1] "1 " "2"  ""   "4"  ""
```

**edit**
Ronaks current solution works for the previous example, but fails when there are other characters than "numbers", either before or after the delimiter.

```r
x <- c("1 - 2","2-1", "-3", "4", "-5-6", "-0.6", "20/200", "20/200-3")

stringr::str_match(x, '(-?\\d+)-?')[, 2]
#> [1] "1"  "2"  "-3" "4"  "-5" "-0" "20" "20"
```

desired output

```
#> [1] "1"  "2"  "-3" "4"  "-5" "-0.6" "20/200" "20/200"
```

(For the curious: this is for conversion of notations of visual acuity data, which tells us how well we can discriminate letters on a chart. This data can be sometimes very messy, but follows generally a certain pattern of notation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to get what you want:

```
str_extract(x, "(-)?\\d+[.\\d/]*(?=-?)")
[1] "1"      "2"      "-3"     "4"      "-5"     "-0.6"   "20/200" "20/200"
```

This matches an optional `-` followed by a number of one or more digits followed by either `.` or a number or `/` zero or more times (`*`) to the left of (`(?= ...)`) an optional `-`

**EDIT**:

A `base R`solution is this:

```
unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("^(-)?\\d+[.\\d/]*(?=-?)", x, perl = T)))
[1] "1"      "2"      "-3"     "4"      "-5"     "-0.6"   "20/200" "20/200"
```

Data:

```
x <- c("1 - 2","2-1", "-3", "4", "-5-6", "-0.6", "20/200", "20/200-3")
```

Comment: Pretty awesome! I am awarding you with my personal regex guru badge :) (would love to upvote at least twice;)

Comment: I just worked out (and wanted to document for the future reader) that this solution works with any character (not only numbers) when replacing  `d` with `w`

Comment: And also for the future reader - str_extract is safer, because it does not omit NA values

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(x, '(-?\\d+)-?')[, 2]
#[1] "1"  "2"  "-3" "4"  "-5"
```

This captures an optional `"-"` followed by a number which is followed by another optional `"-"`.

---

Using `str_extract` :

```
stringr::str_extract(x, '-?\\d+(?=-?)')
```

and in base R :

```
sub("(-?\\d+)-?.*", "\\1", x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - accepted for my example. Unfortunately, it fails when the string contains other characters then numbers - in particular, it should work for decimals and fractions (e.g., "-0.1", "20/200"). I tried `.*` instead of `\\d+` but this failed tooo...:(. any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm...can you include those example in the question along with their expected output?

Comment: @Tjebo I think you should unaccept the answer since I do not have a quick solution for this now but somebody else might be able to help you.